# Unable to upload multiple images with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a view where I can upload images at to a single model which has a foreign key to another model. The below given API works but however it only uploads 1 image. What am I doing wrong that it only takes the first image from the list and uploads in the media folder?

models.py

```
class RoofImages(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    job = models.ForeignKey(JobDetails, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=current_user_id)
    image_type = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=ROOF_VIEW_TYPES)
```

helpers.py

```
def modify_input_for_multiple_files(user, job, image, image_type):
 image_dict = {}
 image_dict['user'] = user
 image_dict['job'] = job
 image_dict['image'] = image
 image_dict['image_type'] = image_type
 return image_dict
```

views.py

```
class RoofImagesView(APIView):
    serializer_class = RoofImagesSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = Token.objects.get(key=request.auth.key).user
        job = request.data['job']
        images = dict((request.data).lists())['image']
        image_type = request.data['image_type']
        flag = True
        arr = []

        for img_name in images:
            modified_data = modify_input_for_multiple_files(user.user_uid, job, img_name, image_type)
            serializer = RoofImagesSerializer(data=modified_data)

            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                arr.append(serializer.data)
            else:
                flag = False
            
            if flag:
                response_content = {
                    'status': True,
                    'message': 'Images uploaded successfully.',
                    'result': arr
                }
                return Response(response_content, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                response_content = {
                    'status': False,
                    'message': 'Unable to upload images.',
                    'result': serializer.errors
                }
                return Response(response_content, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Below is example with response that it only uploads 1 image

[Request screenshot with response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QaY6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, in `RoofImagesSerializer` you need to define the `create` function.

```
def RoofImagesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_file = serializers.FileField(max_length = 1000000, write_only = True)
    
    ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        image_uri = validated_data.pop("image_file")
        roof_image = RoofImages(**validated_data)
        roof_image.image = image_uri
        roof_image.save()
        return roof_image
```

And of course in `modify_input_for_multiple_files` function, `image` key should be changed into `image_file`

```
def modify_input_for_multiple_files(user, job, image, image_type):
    image_dict = {}
    image_dict['user'] = user
    image_dict['job'] = job
    image_dict['image_file'] = image       # here I changed the key
    image_dict['image_type'] = image_type
    return image_dict
```

And also the logic in `for` loop is not correct. I think `if flag` statement should be out of the `for` loop.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    flag = True
    arr = []

    for img_name in images:
        modified_data = modify_input_for_multiple_files(user.user_uid, job, img_name, image_type)
        serializer = RoofImagesSerializer(data=modified_data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            arr.append(serializer.data)
        else:
            flag = False

    # here I changed
    if flag:
        response_content = {
            'status': True,
            'message': 'Images uploaded successfully.',
            'result': arr
        }
        return Response(response_content, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        response_content = {
            'status': False,
            'message': 'Unable to upload images.',
            'result': serializer.errors
        }
        return Response(response_content, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: ```image_file``` does not exists in models so it shows RoofImages got an unexpected argument. Tried replacing ```image_file``` with ```image``` for the same logic but that uploads 1 image only.

Comment: `image_file` does not exist in models, but does exist in serializer.

Comment: Maybe the `for` loop logic is not correct, so I'll add that part.